# No visible @interface for 'NSDate' declares the selector 'initWithString:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSDate initWithString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770257/nsdate-initwithstring)

I wrote the following line of code:

```
[[NSDate alloc] initWithString:@"2013-03-24 10:45:32 +0200"];
```

When I try to compile I obtain the following error message:

ARC Semantic Issue:
No visible @interface for 'NSDate' declares the selector 'initWithString:'

In project there is following include:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

To be sure that class is included, I tried following line which is compiled without issues:

```
[[NSDate alloc] init];
```

What is wrong with my code?

XCode version 4.6.
Base SDK in project iOS 6.1.

Comment: I found answer also at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7803929/13441

Answer (score 4, accepted):

initWithString function is not present in NSDate class for iOS Platforms, since you'll need to first specify a date formatter using NSDateFormatter which converts textual representations of dates and times into NSDate objects. Use something like this :

```
NSString *currentDateString = @"2013-03-24 10:45:32";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *currentDate = [dateFormater dateFromString:currentDateString];
```

Comment: There is method at class https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html . But it seems I missed that is on OS X only, and not on iOS...

Comment: To be more precise the `initWithString:` method is not available for `NSDate` on iOS platforms. On Mac OS X platforms there is an `initWithString:` method available.

Comment: yyyy-MM-DD to yyyy-MM-dd